# android 9 patch doesn't work as I want

Tags: android, nine-patch

Picture showed bellow is my nine patch file. I just want to center the icon as the arrow point to.

[image]

I palced the nite patch file in xhdpi, my xml is like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/kkkkkkkkkk" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the preview is correct, the white icon is exactly placed in center. When I run this application, the result turned out to be like this:

[image]

If I placed this picture in hdpi or xxhdpi, the result is corret. I have no idea about this, could any one of you can help with this?

My test device is Galaxy Note3. Thank you :-)

Comment: try setting width and height as wrap_content and then check..

Comment: @AngadTiwari I need to set width as 80dp, it can't be modified

Comment: ok @withparadox2 ...let do a trick here..

Comment: add one more pix to the top-right and left-bottom...and then see the result

Comment: @AngadTiwari yes it worked, you can consider writing this as an answer, thank you very much, and can you tell me why it would do the trick?

Comment: well...as i seen the patching is more on top-left and bottom-left part of the image..hence just do the trick to increase the patch pixel from opposite side..thats it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add one more pixel to the top-right and left-bottom...and then see the result

Comment: Why does increasing the stretch area make a difference? I only had to do this for xxhdmi and xxxhdmi images.

Answer (score 0):

Check this guide :

[Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

It should help understand better how to support multiple screen sizes.

Comment: To sum it up, you need 4 different picture sizes for the same picture, and place them in their respective folder: The extra large one - in xxhdpi, the large one in hdpi, the medium one in mdpi and the small one in ldpi.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your button with `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_id"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    > 


<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/kkkkkkkkkk" />

</FrameLayout>
```